# Setting Margin between Icon and Hint of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

I have taken an EditText as follows :

```
 <EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="This is text"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

What if I want to set some spaces between that drawable icon and hint of EditText ?

Comment: Use `android:drawablePadding` to set padding for the drawable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this use the attribute `drawablePadding`. This adds some padding between text and image.

Answer (score 2):

Use android:drawablePadding property.
eg. android:drawablePadding="5dp"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="This is text"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add These Two Lines Of Code And you are good to go your icon will not touch the border of EditText and your icon and hint has some space in between As you can see in the pictures below**

```
<EditText
 android:drawablePadding="10dp"
 android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>
```

[image][image]